# GOES-16 - Make Image fit US

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver

I've searched through the posts here and can't seem to figure this out. I am pulling in netCDF's from [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/gcp-public-data-goes-16/ABI-L2-MCMIPC/2018/233/18/?pli=1), and processing them to display on a map. So far I have it in a GeoTIFF format that I can view with QGIS3, but it is not at the right projection/warp. I'm trying to make it so that if you look down from above it lines up on a CONUS map like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1btfkm9XF_nb8W4xRmt-WrMGCZ_L5YQLW).

Here's what I'm doing so far:

`export GDAL_NETCDF_BOTTOMUP=NO
gdal_translate NETCDF:OR_ABI-L2-MCMIPC-M3_G16_s20182331832322_e20182331835095_c20182331835209.nc:CMI_C01 -b 1 test.tif`

And that is how I get this [test.tif](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_kdbJ-aNN7uKuOlpY0BpwbfInjM5GHof) but is at a weird angle if you look at it in QGIS3.

So from here, I am trying to make my test.tif look like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1btfkm9XF_nb8W4xRmt-WrMGCZ_L5YQLW) so my GeoServer instance can slice and dice and serve the world.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, working with CONUS ABI L1b radiance data, but have found something that seems to work - using `gdal_translate`, defining a `-projwin`, subsetting to a smaller area, and creating a new netCDF.

`gdal_translate -of netCDF -projwin -3000000 3200000 -2000000 4200000 NETCDF:"original_file.nc":Rad "new_file.nc"`

Within QGIS I was then able to import this new netCDF file as a raster, and setting the project coordinate reference system (CTRL+Shift+P), QGIS handles the reprojection (WGS84 pictured below).

[image: GOES-16 ABI L1b Rad C02 (Red)]